# Why in vs code in the debug console for c++ is there numbers being printed?

Tags: c++

I am printing a maze and it works but sometimes this number comes up or maybey a few, this is the code en_route is a 2d array of bools

```
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout <<".";
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++,std::cout<<".\n.")
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            if(en_route[i][j])      std::cout << "*";
            else                    std::cout << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

[odd circle with number in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbyIW.png)

also unrelated this 2 or another number shows up later on any idea?

```
.**********.
.*****  ***.
.***    ***.
2
.       *  .
.       ** .
. ***  *** .
.** ****** .
.*  *******.
.** *    **.
.
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I suspect that the number is not part of the output. Please confirm that it also occurs when executing the program in other environments, like e.g. directly from command prompt as an executable.

Comment: The  shown code cannot produce an output which is not only `"*"` and `" "` but also more than a single `"."`. Please double check that your [mre] behaves as you describe. Try to avoid need for users input, i.e. please init your array with hardcoded values.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comments. This is not an output, but the same line was output twice in a row, so it is displayed together on the display side.
Since it is twice, "2" is displayed.
Using the "Terminal" instead of the "Debug Console" will solve the problem.

Comment: thank you very much that explains everything